# File format details informer

Tags: windows, shell, file-format, shell-extensions

In most of recent versions of Windows (XP, Vista, "7") it is possible to get detailed information of some file formats like JPEG EXIF, MP3 ID3 tags (like genre, artist) and some other formats. To get that information one should right click on file, chose "Properties" and check "Details" tab in the dialog.

My question is how do I extend the shell in order to display information about other file formats which are currently not supported or supported but not all details are being shown.

My guess is that there must be some kind of .dll-based mechanism, perhaps some kind of COM server but I can't find the entry point for this topic. I am even not sure how to google it, in fact. Any time I try to search I get a lot of information about file formats rather than shell extension.

Any pointer to relevant article/MSDN chapter is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the IShellPropSheeExt Interface. I think, that's what you want:

[Implementing the Property Page COM Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677109%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions - Part V](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)